# I got an error when I run my codes in R Studio

Tags: r, data-wrangling

Here are the codes that I use

```
library(quantmod)
library(timetk)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)


mdate <- "2015-10-30"
edate <- "2016-01-05"

tickers <- c("ABG","ACH","ADM","AEG","AEM","AGQ","AGRO","AKOb","APO")


data <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, lapply(tickers, function(x) 
  getSymbols(x, from = mdate, to = edate, auto.assign = F)))


# Transpose data.frame: 
td_data <- within(data.frame(price_var = row.names(t(data)), t(data), row.names = NULL), 
                  {
                    ticker_cd <- as.factor(gsub("[.].*", "", price_var))
                    price_var <- as.factor(gsub(".*[.]", "", price_var))
                  }
)
# Reshape: 
abc <- do.call("cbind", split(td_data, td_data$price_var))
```

When I run these I got:

Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 44, 38
In addition: Warning message:
AKOb contains missing values. Some functions will not work if objects contain missing values in the middle of the series. Consider using na.omit(), na.approx(), na.fill(), etc to remove or replace them.

I found that this error was caused by "AKOB". The data from first and sixth days are blank, so the first day of "AKOB" stars on Nov 9th 2015 which is different than other stock data. The way I found was to run one by one and compared their differences. It is very inefficient way whenever it happens.

I want to skip if a stock has no data in my setting (from start date to end date)
How can I do to do this?

Comment: Break the line into separate parts so that the result of `lapply( ... )` is returned as an object. Then use `lapply` on that object to check for blank values for each ticket and remove the ones that have blanks before calling `cbind.data.frame`.

Comment: @Dongchul Park I am not sure what you are trying to achieve.  Do you want to impute, interpolate, drop AKOB altogether, or leave NA values as they are ? If the latter (please see my solution below).

Comment: @hello_friend, the thing I wanted to make is that I did not want to include AKOB in the final output, "abc", since this ticker has N/A. In other words, I want to import data of "ABG","ACH","ADM","AEG","AEM","AGQ","AGRO","APO" in "abc". Anyway the codes that you wrote below will be very useful for me.

Comment: @hello_friend. Also if there is no data in the time peoriod, another error happens. For example if "JJA" is included in tickers, the code you wrote below wouldn't work. Can I import data only when a ticker has completed value? Since I try to get 45 days value (From mdate to edate), all data of tickers shown in "abc" must has 45 values in each category (Open, High, Low, Close, Adjusted and Volume). Is it possible?

Comment: @Dongchul Park see revised solution below.

Comment: Accept my solution if it does what you require

Comment: @hello_friend. Thank you so much for the help. Unfortunately, when I run with      tickers <- c("ABG","ACH","ADM","AEG","AEM","AGQ","AGRO","AKOb","APO","JJA"), an error is still there:        "Error in getSymbols.yahoo(Symbols = "JJA", env = <environment>, verbose = FALSE,  : 
  Unable to import “JJA”.
JJA download failed after two attempts. Error message:
HTTP error 400. "       Isn't there no solution for this?

Comment: This is the error if you run these code: "Error in getSymbols.yahoo(Symbols = "JJA", env = <environment>, verbose = FALSE,  : 
  Unable to import “JJA”.
JJA download failed after two attempts. Error message:
HTTP error 400."

Comment: @DongchulPark please view my solution below and accept it if it does what you require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(quantmod)

mdate <- "2015-10-30"
edate <- "2016-01-05"

tickers <- c("ABG","ACH","ADM","AEG","AEM","AGQ","AGRO","AKOb","APO", "JJE")

# Iterate through the tickers and retrieve data from Yahoo Finance defensively: data => xts
data <- do.call("cbind", lapply(seq_along(tickers), function(i){
        try_var <- try(getSymbols(tickers[i], from = mdate, to = edate, auto.assign = FALSE))
        if(inherits(try_var, "try-error")) {
          i <- i + 1
        } else{
          getSymbols(tickers[i], from = mdate, to = edate, auto.assign = FALSE)   
        }
      }
    )
  )



# Transpose data.frame: td_data => data.frame
td_data <- within(data.frame(price_var = row.names(t(data)), t(data), row.names = NULL), 
                  {
                    ticker_cd <- as.factor(gsub("[.].*", "", price_var))
                    price_var <- as.factor(gsub(".*[.]", "", price_var))
                  }
                )

# Re-order vectors; keep complete cases: td_data_o => data.frame
td_data_o <- td_data[complete.cases(td_data), 
                     c(names(td_data)[sapply(td_data, is.factor)],  
                       names(td_data)[sapply(td_data, function(x){!is.factor(x)})])]

# Reshape: abc => data.frame
abc <- do.call("cbind", split(td_data_o, td_data_o$price_var))
```